# How to replace and convert # list to html ul list Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to [string#replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) using regex to convert the following

```
# title 1
# title 2
# title 3
```

to

```
<ul>
 <li>title 1</li>
 <li>title 2</li>
 <li>title 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: *"How to replace using regex"* Don't. You **will** run into edge cases that don't work. Use a parser.

Comment: *"The markup has other components like p tag, a tag not only the ul list."* Then show a realistic example. Are those elements *in* the list? Outside it? Nested? Malformed, as so much HTML is?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added please check the update, need to plug in # list inside these current components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with two **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var div = document.getElementById('content');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML
  // wrap all elements with ul
  .replace(/(((?:^|\n)\s*)[\*#](.*))+/g, '<ul>$&\n</ul>')
  // wrap all line with li
  .replace(/((?:<ul>\n?|\n)\s*)[\*#](.*)/g, '$1<li>$2</li>');
```

```html
<div id="content">
  # title 1
  # title 2
  # title 3
</div>
```

Comment: Respect man! Thank you,This is working, this was really a tricky one.

Comment: @reverbnation : glad to help :)